# ACF: Querying relationship fields with Author

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

I have a website which is about local types of foods and drinks. On the website, businesses can create a user and via the relationship field - add foods and drinks they offer.

The relationship field `'resturant'` is displayed at `/wp-admin/profile.php` for logged in users.

Foods and drinks pages:

```
website.com/food/
website.com/food/cherry-pie/
website.com/food/pancakes/
website.com/food/cookies/
website.com/drinks/
website.com/drinks/lemonade/
website.com/drinks/soda/
website.com/drinks/water/
```

Three registered users:

```
website.com/author/resturant-cuppa-joes/
website.com/author/resturant-mclovin/
website.com/author/resturant-hotcup/
```

> User Resturant Cuppa Joe's and Resturant MClovin have for example added Cherry Pie as one of the meals they offer. User Resturant Hotcup have not. When someone visits the page `website.com/food/cherry-pie/` I want Resturant Cuppa Joe's and Resturant MClovin to be featured there, and not Resturant Hotcup.

In page.php I have the following code:

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

            <h2>Resturants</h2>
            <?php 

            $resturants = get_users(array( // Changed from get_posts
                'meta_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'key' => 'resturant', // name of custom field
                        'value' => '"' . get_the_ID() . '"',
                        'compare' => 'LIKE'
                    )
                )
            ));

            ?>
            <?php if( $resturants ): ?>
                <ul>
                <?php foreach( $resturants as $resturant ): ?>
                    <li>
                        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $resturant->ID ); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title( $resturant->ID ); ?></a>
                    </li>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                </ul>
            <?php endif; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Used the sample at [advancedcustomfields.com](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/querying-relationship-fields/), changed `get_posts` to `get_users`.

Something seems to be right - **I get a list with two links**, but the links point to the start page.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The users doesn't have permalinks nor titles. They have author links and display names. Changed the code:

```
            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                        <h2>Resturants</h2>
                        <?php 

                        $resturants = get_users(array( // Changed from get_posts
                            'fields' => 'all_with_meta', // All with meta to get also display_name
                            'meta_query' => array(
                                array(
                                    'key' => 'resturant', // name of custom field
                                    'value' => '"' . get_the_ID() . '"',
                                    'compare' => 'LIKE'
                                )
                            )
                        ));

                        ?>
                        <?php if( $resturants ): ?>
                            <ul>
                            <?php foreach( $resturants as $resturant ): ?>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url( $resturant->ID ); ?>"><?php echo $resturant->display_name; ?></a>
                                </li>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                            </ul>
                        <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm.